# Core Data predicate for any row of the associated entity

Tags: core-data, many-to-many, any

In the following I will describe a simplification of my Core Data schema that I am pretty sure to be equivalent to my real situation.

[image]

I have two entity `First` and `Second` linked by a many-to-many relationship `r`.

`Second` has got two Boolean attribute, let us call it `take` and `you_should_not_take`.
I want to make a query that select a row of `First` iff it exits an associated row of `Second` for with `take = true`.

I have tried this predicate:

```
NSPredicate(format: "ANY (%K == YES && %K == NO)", "r.take","r.you_should_not_take")
```

but Core Data gives me the following error: `"[General] Unable to parse the format string"`.

Maybe I have to use this:

```
NSPredicate(format: "((ANY %K == YES) && (ANY %K == NO))", "r.take","r.you_should_not_take")
```

but I am afraid that this last query will select a row of `First` iff it exists a row `x` of `Second` for which `x.take == YES` && it exists a row `y` if `Second` for which `y.you_should_not_take == NO`, with no guarantee that `x == y`.

An SQL query would be very simple to be made, but I am not so experienced with Core Data, so while I will try some more queries (and I will test if the second query does what I think it does) I have also asked here hoping the answer would be as simple as in SQL.

Comment: Why not just `NSPredicate(format: "ANY %K == YES", "r.take")` ?

Comment: @MartinR The two attributes in the original schema are uncorrelated, I could have chooses different names for this question.

Comment: So you want to select all First objects which are related to (at least one) Second object for which `take==true` and `you_should_not_take==false` ? Is that correct?

Comment: @MartinR, exactly

Comment: Soory I didn't remembered to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select all *First* objects which are related to (at least one) *Second* object for which `take==true` and `you_should_not_take==false` you have 
to use a SUBQUERY. Something like (untested):

```
SUBQUERY(r, $x, $x.take == YES AND $x.you_should_not_take == NO).@count > 0
```

Comment: Working perfectly!